System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'
I'm trying to learn the basics of a Marketplace SaaS process by following along with the "Mastering the Marketplace" labs:
https://github.com/Azure/mtm-labs
I've done all the Azure setup for the first lab of creating my landing page and it all works fine on localhost (suggesting my App.config settings are correct from the Azure app setup).
I already have an IIS Windows server that I want to host the site on eventually, so want to deploy to that instead of the Azure host in the lab sample. When I deployed to my existing server and try to login, I get an error about unable to obtain a configuration file and this stack trace:
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
 ---> System.TimeoutException: A task was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsyncInternal(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|28_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

In my appsettings.json, I have:
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "officeaddins.co.uk",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "ClientId": "xxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxxx"
  },

That Domain value is the domain registered in my Azure tenant, but the code is being deployed to a subdomain, test.officeaddins.co.uk. Does that make a difference?
In the Azure config, I've added https://test.officeaddins.co.uk/ and https://test.officeaddins.co.uk/signin-oidc as valid Redirect URIs.
Lots of pages with similar issues suggest it's something to do with web.config authentication/authorization settings, but if that's the problem what should I have in web.config to be able to run that sample?
EDIT (after the help from @architect-jamie):
The issue is that my web site host (Ionos) requires the use of a proxy to connect to other sites. I tried adding a global proxy in web.config, but that didn't help (Does ASP.Net 4.8 use that?).
So I've added proxy handlers (options.BackchannelHttpHandler) in startup.cs:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Configure AAD and Graph integration
    // This enables SSO for AAD and access to the user's graph information
    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(this.Configuration) // Sign on with AAD
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" }) // Call Graph API
            .AddMicrosoftGraph() // Use defaults with Graph V1
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches(); // Add token caching

    // Configure OpenIdConnect
    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = (context) =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
            context.HandleResponse();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
        options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseProxy = true,
            Proxy = new WebProxy()
            {
                Address = new Uri("http://winproxy.server.lan:3128")
            }
        };
    });

    // validate attributes in the JWT claims - audience and issuer
    // use the appsettings.json or environmental variables for Configuration access
    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = this.Configuration["MarketplaceApi:ClientId"];
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{this.Configuration["MarketplaceApi:TenantId"]}/";
            options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseProxy = true,
                Proxy = new WebProxy()
                {
                    Address = new Uri("http://winproxy.server.lan:3128")
                }
            };
        });

    // add the marketplace client to services
    ConfigureMarketplaceServices(services);

    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });

    services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
}

That gets me a step further, but now getting an error of:
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
 ---> System.TimeoutException: A task was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsyncInternal(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|28_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

So it seems I need to somehow override / inject the proxy HttpClientHandler in the Services config generically, but how?

Looking at the error, it seems your web server is not able to access the metadata endpoint URL. It needs to retrieve the authorisation endpoints for your organisation, among other things. This metadata endpoint URL is a well-known address specific to your Tenant Id, or primary domain.
Log on to your VM hosting your landing page, open powershell, run this:
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/officeaddins.co.uk/.well-known/openid-configuration" -Method GET
This should return a JSON document with a bunch of URLs. If it doesn't, you have internet connectivity issues on the server.
Edit:

That Domain value is the domain registered in my Azure tenant, but the code is being deployed to a subdomain, test.officeaddins.co.uk. Does that make a difference?

Nope.

Thanks Jamie. It's a proxy issue, but I think I'm missing setting one somewhere. Any idea which service is used to load the authentication document, that I should add a proxy handler to?

Can you include the new full stacktrace? I think the call chain will be different, even though the error looks the same. We should be able to overcome it by overriding the default IHttpClientFactory in the service configuration. I'll edit my answer when I get 5.

Done, thanks. Yes, overriding that seems to be what I need. I Googled and played a bit with the services.AddHttpClient() but couldn't work out what parameters it needed to define the proxy.

Thanks for all your help Jamie, setting HttpClient.DefaultProxy gets it all working on my site host!

Sometimes too much Googling takes us down endless rabbit-holes. Thanks to @Architect-Jamie, my issues was traced to my web site host requiring a proxy connection to be defined for all my connections requests. That can be done globally when configuring the application by setting a default proxy to use when not in the Development (LocalHost) environment - there's probably a better way to say "When not running on LocalHost":
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy("http://winproxy.server.lan:3128", true);
            }

